# sql query how to work out highest earner in a day

Tags: php, mysql

Im currently looping through the stylists for a particular date and trying to find which one has made the most money.  I'm struggling to get past the part i'm up to.  I have looped through my query but now I don't know what to do with it. Once I have my array of price how do i order it like I need to?

```
foreach ($staffArray as $staff) {
    $query = sprintf(
               "SELECT SUM(bookingPrice) as price 
                FROM booking 
                WHERE idsystem=%s AND 
                      idbranch=%s AND 
                      bookingDate=%s AND 
                      idStatus=%s AND 
                      idstylist=%s",
               $this->db->GetSQLValueString($this->mysystem, "int"),
               $this->db->GetSQLValueString($this->branch, "int"),
               $this->db->GetSQLValueString($this->dateToday, "date"),
               $this->db->GetSQLValueString('1', "int"),
               $this->db->GetSQLValueString($staff, "int")
               );
    $result = $this->db->query($query); 
    $row = $this->db->fetch_assoc($result);
}
```

Comment: Use a real prepared statement instead of that `sprintf()` workaround. Also you might save some time, when issuing the query for all `$staff` as one query and not separately.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To get this particular code working, you could do something like:

```
$prices = array(); // here we're going to store your data
foreach ($staffArray as $staff) {
    $query = sprintf("...", ...); 
    $result = $this->db->query($query);
    $row = $this->db->fetch_assoc($result);
    $prices[/* name of stylist */] = /* value to sort on */;
}
asort($prices); // Sort the array, keep the keys
foreach ($prices as $stylist => $price) {
    echo "$stylist: $price";
}
```

However, it would be better to use **one** query for everything instead of that `foreach` loop, to let MySQL sort instead of PHP, and to use prepared statements instead of `sprintf`.

Comment: If you also mention the better solution, why just give the worse one?

Comment: @Sirko from the question it's clear OP has some issues with arrays. I don't think he's on the level of more complex SQL queries and prepared statements yet, though I may be mistaken. I won't give him the code if it wouldn't teach him something. Anyway, how to use prepared statements is already extensively discussed elsewhere.

Comment: @CamilStaps your correct I've never used or heard of prepared statements.  Looks like I've got a bit of reading to do

Comment: @DanielRobinson prepared statements are important, but not as long as you're just playing around. If you're in a professional context or if you think people are going to use your system, it's essential - but if you just want to learn PHP, it's not (still good, but not essential).

Comment: @CamilStaps thanks dude.  This actually is for a massive system Ive built thats currently running in a salon.  I see many places now where a prepared statement would of come in handy.  I still don't really get them either so not changing anything yet until I do.  Ill just have to miss this report out for now until i understand how to write these and what they are doing.